Issue Running on Uniswap V3: [Describe specific error or problem]
I’m having trouble running the Uniswap interface locally.
I cloned the repository and ran yarn, but an error message appeared.
➤ YN0009: │ universe@workspace:. couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: C:\Users\Top\AppData\Local\Temp\xfs-e5b7cefd\build.log)
➤ YN0009: │ postinstall-postinstall@npm:2.1.0 couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: C:\Users\Top\AppData\Local\Temp\xfs-7ed96acb\build.log)
How to solve this problem?
